# Laravel breaks when I remove .env file

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables

In my production environment I have removed the .env file so it uses the actual values in the config folder...or so I thought.

Well, after I removed the .env file now my entire site is broken and there is no error message.

What am I doing wrong? I just want my site to use the config values in production.

Comment: Have you checked your `php_error.log` as well as your Laravel log? Also, have you definitely set all the env vars in your config i.e. `APP_KEY`?

Comment: Search in your project about any `env()` call, if you delete the .env file it will throw an error.

Comment: Thanks Troyer. I ended up just creating a .env file specifically for the production environment. Seems to work now.

Comment: @kjdion84 That's the whole point.. to have an env file to define values for an environment.

Comment: Right, but I had assumed the env() function would check if the file exists, else it would use the value specified. That made more sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel uses the [DotEnv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) library for configuration. If you want different settings for a development environment simply create a different file for this purpose, but remember:

> Your .env file should not be committed to your application's source control, since each developer / server using your application could require a different environment configuration. Furthermore, this would be a security risk in the event an intruder gain access to your source control repository, since any sensitive credentials would get exposed.

Source: [Laravel configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/configuration)